# How to implement Read more / Read less in pure CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, toggle

I am implementing a CSS read more / read less capability using http://codepen.io/Idered/pen/AeBgF as a starting point.

I modified it to work off `<p>` tags vs. `<li>` list items.

I can't get the code to work on my page at http://bit.ly/1L5vMm7

**Here is my version of the CSS:**

```
input.read-more-state {
    display: none;
}

p.read-more-target {
    font-size: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .25s ease;
}

input.read-more-state:checked ~ div.read-more-wrap p.read-more-target {
    font-size: inherit;
    max-height: 999em;
    opacity: 1;
}

input.read-more-state ~ label.read-more-trigger:before {
    content: 'Read more';
}

input.read-more-state:checked ~ label.read-more-trigger:before {
    content: 'Read less';
}

label.read-more-trigger {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<input class="read-more-state" id="read-more-controller" type="checkbox">
<div class="read-more-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <p class="read-more-target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <p class="read-more-target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <p class="read-more-target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
<label class="read-more-trigger" for="read-more-controller"></label>
```

Let me know if you can discover what is conflicting with the RM/RL utility.

Comment: You are using sibling selectors and CSS cannot traverse the DOM upwards when selecting elements. Move the `input` and `label` to be above the `div`.

Comment: Thanks @Harry, I'l post back once I fix that.

Comment: Ok, while that makes sense @Harry, The "Read more" / "Read less" control link [*now*] appears above the content and not within the content. Not sure why it works for the Codepen author and not in my document flow.

Comment: Put the `<input>` before the `<div>` so that you can use the sibling selector. Put the `<label>` after the `<div>` so it appears below the content.

Comment: `Put the <input> before the <div> so that you can use the sibling selector. Put the <label> after the <div> so it appears below the content.` I started with that @DarkFalcon and the Show more content is not clickable. Check out the page now.

Comment: @H.Ferrence: In the codepen the `input` is above the `div`. The sibling selector is between the `input` and `div` (and `input` and `label`) and hence just moving `input` alone to top would be enough. This is what is done in the CodePen. Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpztmxem/).

Comment: Well I am admittedly an *idiot* on this. I feel my markup looks exactly like your fiddle. I simply don't get it...@Harry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**How does the CodePen achieve this behavior?**

All that the code in the demo does is modify the `max-height` of the wrapper `div` based on the check-box being checked or unchecked and whilst doing so also change the content of the `label`.

Now lets have a look at the key individual selectors in CSS that help perform this:

`.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target`

- This selector means that when an `input` with `class = 'read-more-state'` is checked, select the elements with `class = 'read-more-target'` which are present under a wrapper with `class = 'read-more-wrap'` when the wrapper is also a  sibling of the checkbox (the reference element).

`.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before`

- This is the one that populates the default text for the `label`. What it does is set the `content` as **"Show more"** for the `::before` element of `label` with `class = 'read-more-trigger'` when the `label` is also a sibling of the checkbox.

`.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before`

- This is the one that modifies the text of the `label` when the checkbox is clicked. The selector means that when the `input` with `class = 'read-more-state'` is `:checked`, set the `content` of the label's before element as **"Show less"**.

Also, note the `for` attribute in the `label` tag. The value of this field points to the `id` of the `input` tag and so whenever the label is clicked, the `input` element's state gets toggled automatically. This will happen irrespective of where in DOM the `label` and `input` elements are.

```css
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}
.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}
.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}
.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show more';
}
.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show less';
}
.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
/* Other style */

body {
  padding: 2%;
}
p {
  padding: 2%;
  background: #fff9c6;
  color: #c7b27e;
  border: 1px solid #fce29f;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-1" />

  <p class="read-more-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span class="read-more-target">Libero fuga facilis vel consectetur quos sapiente deleniti eveniet dolores tempore eos deserunt officia quis ab? Excepturi vero tempore minus beatae voluptatem!</span>
  </p>

  <label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-2" />

  <ul class="read-more-wrap">
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>lorem 2</li>
    <li class="read-more-target">lorem 3</li>
    <li class="read-more-target">lorem 4</li>
  </ul>

  <label for="post-2" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
</div>
```

---

**Why does my code not work?**

CSS selectors can select a sibling element only when it is present after/below the reference element in the DOM. In your snippet, the `div` which needs to be selected is present after the `input` (which is the reference element and whose state triggers the action) and hence CSS is not able to select it. No selection results in no property change being applied.

```css
input.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}
p.read-more-target {
  font-size: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}
input.read-more-state:checked ~ div.read-more-wrap p.read-more-target {
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
  opacity: 1;
}
input.read-more-state ~ label.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Read more';
}
input.read-more-state:checked ~ label.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Read less';
}
label.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="read-more-wrap">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <p class="read-more-target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <p class="read-more-target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <p class="read-more-target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
<input class="read-more-state" id="read-more-controller" type="checkbox">
<label class="read-more-trigger" for="read-more-controller"></label>
```

---

**How can I solve this problem?**

Just move the `input` tag  to be above the wrapper `div` tag whose `max-height` needs to be changed when the label is clicked. Doing this would mean that the reference element is now above the element that needs to be selected and styled. Thus, CSS would be able to apply the `max-height` properly and reveal the hidden contents.

```css
input.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}
p.read-more-target {
  font-size: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}
input.read-more-state:checked ~ div.read-more-wrap p.read-more-target {
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
  opacity: 1;
}
input.read-more-state ~ label.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Read more';
}
input.read-more-state:checked ~ label.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Read less';
}
label.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input class="read-more-state" id="read-more-controller" type="checkbox">
<div class="read-more-wrap">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <p class="read-more-target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <p class="read-more-target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <p class="read-more-target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
<label class="read-more-trigger" for="read-more-controller"></label>
```

Comment: Nice @Harry. I'll read through; digest; test; and post back shortly. I greatly appreciate your assistance in helping me solve the problem. I like this RM/RL functionality and want it to work on my site so I can re-use it down the road as well.

Comment: Sorry @Harry, but I am simpley stupid on this. I just don't get it. What is so different about your answer, your code snippet, and your fiddle from that of my web document? Everything works but my web doc which is identical to your scaled back snippets.

Comment: SO IS MINE -- how totally frustrating this is ` width="270"><input class="read-more-state" id="read-more-controller" type="checkbox"><div class="read-more-wrapper"><p>Rob`

Comment: Exactly. I just don't know where/what the conflict is. Hence the reason for my post.

Comment: Running **Google Chrome Version 44.0.2403.155 m** (I keep my IE, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome browsers latest & greatest the moment new release come out)

Comment: The page does not work on Safari 5.1.7, Firefox 39.0, Opera 31.0, IE 11.0.9600.17914, and Chrome 44.0.2403.155 m -- all on a PC

Comment: That is not a duplicate `id`

Comment: @H.Ferrence: Ok I got it. It seems like some other element is overlapping your label which is resulting in the click actually not happening on the label. Add `position: relative; z-index: 2` to the label to bring it forward and see it works :) (I am removing older comments to keep the discussion short).

Comment: Good tip @Harry -- `It seems like the checkbox itself is not getting checked when the label is clicked.`. I changed my css to "not hide" the checkbox. Now when I check and uncheck the checkbox, the functionality works completely. Just need to figure out how or why the checkbox is not working (without reverting to a jQuery/Javascript solution which I was trying to avoid in lieu of using a pure css solution)

Comment: @H.Ferrence: It is because your label is not clickable. Please try the change I mentioned in my previous comment and it should clear it off.

Comment: Oh you're brilliant @Harry...that worked ! Thank you so, so, very, very much. I spent hours banging my head against the wail on this.

Comment: No problems mate. Always happy to help :)