# Automatic read more using child selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Anyone know if it's possible to automatically generate a read more link and tag using purely child elements? Apologies if my terminology is off.

For example, my content looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
    <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
    <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
</div>
```

Ideally I'd love to automatically clip all content after the first `<p>`, display a Read More link inline before the first p ends, and have that read more link show or hide any other elements within the div.container.

It feels simple, but I'm sure its not. Any ideas?

Comment: You can add an element under the last child of selected div class. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way. Other than to restrict the height and width to the "read more" size. Then loop over all the elements in the container and add up their height and see if it's taller. And then append the read more ellipses if need be. Then attach the click to the ellipses to set the height to auto.

That would be much easier than trying to detect the text and see how much which letters exactly flow out.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968211/how-to-implement-read-more-read-less-in-pure-css

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container p:first-child').append('<a>Read More</a>');
$('.container p:not(:first-child)').hide();


$('.container').on("click", "a", function() {
   $('.container p:not(:first-child)').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This offloads as much of the logic into the CSS as possible, though all the event handling needs to be done in javascript.  I included two container block to demonstrate that it works on each one individually, and as an added frill toggle the 'read more' link text to match its function.

```js
$('.container').each(function() {
  var container = this;
  $('<a href="#">Read more</a>')
    .appendTo($(container).find('p:first'))
    .click(function() {
      $(container).toggleClass('readmore');
      this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML === 'Read more') ? "Read less" : 'Read more';
  });
});
```

```css
.container p:not(:first-child) {
  display: none
}

.container.readmore p:not(:first-child) {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
  <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
  <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit etcetera.</p>
</div>
```